# How to run specific test class in subfolder with maven command?

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I have a question in regards to running a single test class through maven. More specifically, I have a project structure which looks like this:

[image]

And I would like to run the integration test inside the `StatusSocketIT` class through a maven command. I tried therefore the following maven command:

```
mvn test -Dtest=todolist.websocket.src.it.java.org.smart.todolist.websocket.StatusSocketIT
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project backend: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

which tells that the tests cant be executed. I have also tried other path names like for instance `org.smart.todolist.websocket.StatusSocketIT` but this also throws the same error. Would anyone maybe know what the issue is? Thanks in advance

Comment: First you are violating the convention to keep testing code in `src/test/java` furthertmore you should follow naming conventions which means an integration test should be name like `*IT.java`... on the other hand you are naming an `AbstractIT` which is for sure not an integration test... Apart from that which unit testing framework do you use? Also you are using ancient old version of maven-surefire-plugin which means either you have defined that old version in your build or none..that means in consequence you are using an ancient old Maven verison as well.. Please show more details...

Comment: Also this implies that you are using maven-surefire-plugin to execute integration tests which is even wrong. Integration tests should be running via maven-failsafe-plugin... Using the command line `mvn test -Dtest=...` will not work because you are not following the conventions...

Answer (score 0):

Change the command to:

```
mvn test -Dtest=org.smart.todolist.websocket.StatusSocketIT
```

Only the "path" inside `src/it/java` is part of the class name (its *package*).

In addition, make sure you have the `src/it/java` directory configured as a test directory in your pom file:

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/it/java</testSourceDirectory>
</build>
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! I still see the same error unfortunatelly

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that in your question. See update.

Comment: That is a bad idea to violate the conventions.. tests should be located in `src/test/java/<package>` and only separated by using naming conventions like `*Test.java` unit tests and integration tests `*IT.java` ...also running unit tests via maven-surefire-plugin while integration tests should be executed via maven-failsafe-plugin....